# Active-sqlserver-adapter with Rails 5 application.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, tiny-tds

I am trying to set up a new application with rails 5. I have a half dozen applications working fine with rails 4.x.

When I try to do a bundle install, I get an error that starts with

```
Error:[rake --tasks] DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <top (required)> at C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/user_message_console/config/application.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <top (required)> at C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/user_message_console/config/application.rb:7)
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `add_order!' for class `Class'
Backtrace for gem load error is:
```

If I do a bundle show activerecord I get

```
C:\Users\cmendla\RubymineProjects\user_message_console>bundle show activerecord
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1
```

I've tried both a plain gem and a gem with different versions

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
# gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 5.0.0'
 gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

A bundle install shows an error code of 0

```
Using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 2.3.8
(this is a partial list ).....
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.2.1
Using jquery-rails 4.2.1
Using web-console 3.4.0
Using rails 5.0.0.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 58 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But then I get the error that I posted above . There server I am using is server 2012

There is some info at https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/tree/rails5  but it doesn't seem clear as to if I am loading the right gem version as that document references `gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.2.0'`

If anyone knows of compatibility issues between rails 5 and the ActiveRecord SQL Server Adapter, I can stay with rails 4.x for a bit. Otherwise, I'd like to try to get this working.

Comment: I know this isn't the most helpful advice...but have you tried uninstalling rails / everything? Maybe consider upgrading ruby to version `2.3.1` using rvm so you get / have to install a clean gemset.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently. I solved it by adding the following to the gemfile:

`gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', :github => 'rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', :branch => 'master'`